# For loop doesn't loop my else statement (Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing a simple code that takes an input read by the scanner and saved into a variable `word`.
It is required for an assignment to create a separate method that will take that string and convert all the letters to a '?' mark. At the spaces, however, there should be a space.
The problem is that every time I run this code, it stops at the space.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class commonPhrase {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word;
        System.out.print("Welcome to the Guessing Game.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter a common phrase");
        word = input.next();
        createTemplate(word);
    }
    public static String createTemplate(String word) {
        String sPhrase = "";
        for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) == ' '){
                sPhrase += " ";
            }
            else {
                sPhrase += "?";                 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sPhrase);
        return sPhrase;
    }
}
```

And here is a sample run of it:

> Welcome to the Guessing Game.
>   Please enter a common phrase.
>   Why wont it add spaces!!!!!!!
>   ???

Answer (score 4):

You call `next()` on the `Scanner`, but that method grabs the next token, and by default it's separating tokens by whitespace.  You only gathered one word.

Call `nextLine()` instead, to grab the text of the entire line.

```
word = input.nextLine();
```

Sample run with fix above:

```
Welcome to the Guessing Game.
Please enter a common phrase
Stack Overflow
????? ????????
```

Comment: Wow, how the hell did I miss that.
THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH

Comment: @izzy because you never read the javadoc for [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).